# Good programming practice sharing ArrayList between Activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, arraylist, android-adapter

I am trying to create an Android application to display a set of facts in a main activity where the user is able to add facts to another activity being Favourites.

I am having an issue with sharing/accessing the ArrayList between classes so I can then be able to call update methods (add, remove etc) on the ArrayList. Nor am I sure about the best practice to follow for solving this.

1. Currently I have declared my ArrayList as public static final in MainActivity.java where updates on it are handled and this ArrayList is then accessed in FavouriteActivity.java and assigned to a new ArrayList collection there as can be seen in the code below. This however isn't good programming practice which I am aware of hence my question being posted here for guidance.
2. I don't think I can use an Intent to share/access it as the ArrayList stores objects of  not . I have seen a similar question recommending this however it didn't work for me.
3. I have tried to create an FavouriteActivity object within MainActivity thereby calling a method such as addFavourite() from FavouriteActivity on the ArrayList within that class, however encountered several error with this.
4. I have also tried to devise a constructor for FavouriteActivity which would accept an ArrayList upon creation, thereby passing through the ArrayList from MainActivity. This again didn't work, encountered several issues.

Also ideally where should all of this handling be carried out for the Favourites list? Within MainActivity, FavouriteActivity or FavouriteAdapter?

Thank you all.

**Favourite.java**

This class has two fields, both are Strings to represent an ID and some text. Initialised in constructor and two get methods to return their values.

**FavouriteAdapter.java**

```
imports omitted.

public class FavouriteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Favourite> {

    public FavouriteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Favourite> favourite) {
        super(context, 0, favourite);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.favourite_item, parent, false);
        }

        Favourite currentFavourite = getItem(position);

        TextView idTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_text_view);
        idTextView.setText(currentFavourite.getId());

        TextView textTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_text_view);
        textTextView.setText(currentFavourite.getText());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**FavouriteActivity.java**

This class uses and displays a collection of facts that have been added to the ArrayList using an Adapter and ListView.

```
imports omitted.

public class FavouriteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_favourite);

        ArrayList<Favourite> allFavourites = MainActivity.allFavourites;

        FavouriteAdapter favouriteAdapter = new FavouriteAdapter(FavouriteActivity.this, allFavourites);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(favouriteAdapter);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

This is the main view GUI for the user where the facts are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement Parcelable in Favourite, and pass list into activity.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html